# IF connection lost => kill browser

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am having the following script that monitors when the connection appears => open chrome with a specific url:

```
#!/bin/sh
function online {
  wget -q -O /dev/null --timeout=5 http://URL/
  return $?
}

until online
do
  sleep 5
done


google-chrome --start-fullscreen --incognito "http://URL" &
```

Now **I would like to monitor if connection is lost => kill chrome. What sould be the script for that?**

Tried the below, but it's not the right syntax

```
#!/bin/sh
function offline {
  wget -q -O /dev/null --timeout=5 http://URL/
  return !$?
}

while offline
do
  pkill chrome
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: where is it better o keep it?

Comment: @ihtus, this question is OK here, but it's rude to post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: ok, deleted there, kept here

Comment: As glenn demonstrated (but did not explain) in his answer, you don’t need to say ``return $?`` at the end of a function — the default return value from a function is the exit status of the last command executed.  (And, if you’re going to reference `$?`, you should put it into quotes — `"$?"`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd extend your "launch" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
url="http://URL/"

online() {
  wget -q -O /dev/null --timeout=5 "$url"
}

# infinite loop
while :; do

    # launch chrome when we go online
    until online; do sleep 5; done
    google-chrome --start-fullscreen --incognito "$url" &

    # kill chrome when we go offline
    while online; do sleep 5; done
    pkill chrome

done
```

Comment: This is untested.

Comment: Looks good.  Since the shebang is `/bin/sh`, though, one might replace `function online {` with `online() {` in order to be POSIX compatible.

Answer (score -1):

```
I have included both the conditions in script

wget - -spider “http:url”
If [[ $? == 0 ]]
Then
google-chrome --start-fullscreen --incognito "http://URL" &

Else
Ps -eaf | grep -i chrome | awk ‘{print “kill -9” “ “ $2}’ | sh
```

Comment: I am not sure, your script wasn't generated by a Markov-automat.